# How to check contents of unknown .py process?

Tags: linux, security, archlinux

So I just did a fresh install of Antegros (which is basically Arch with easy installation) using full ISO from official website. I ticked few additional features in installation like printer support, easy firewall, Firefox, etc. I picked XFCE as my DE.

Now right after installation I checked my task manager and there is this odd process running under my user called "applet.py". It consumes 30.3 MiB and sits at 0% CPU usage. It returns my home directory as cwd.

I want to check contents of this py file but I couldn't find a way of doing so after some searching. I can't seem to find anything interesting in /proc/[PID].

How can I read contents of this Python script?

What do you think it actually is? Isn't it kinda odd that py file is running in fresh installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to have a pretty minimal (and fresh) install, I would recommend simply searching the filesystem for the file that is running.

Try:
`find / | grep "applet.py"` (this will need superuser permission).

As long as your installation size is sufficiently small, the search shouldn't take too long.

On two Ubuntu installations I have access to, I found `applet.py` scripts in `/usr/share/system-config-printer/` and `/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_netowrk-manager/`.